# AngularJS routing is slow in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, single-page-application, ngroute

I am using AngularJS for building single page application. The application is responding quite fast in Chrome but in Firefox the routing is slow. The destination page is displayed after 1 or 2 secs after the link is clicked. Are there any issues which I need to look at?

One thing I have noticed is that the routing is slow on the pages where we are using ng-repeat for displaying data.

Comment: No, it should not be slow because of ng-repeat. Maybe your browser is old. try to upgrade it, if so

Comment: I have checked the app with latest version of firefox as well but the routing is still slow for those pages where we need to display quite large amount of  data.

Comment: if you have large amount of data, then it is natural. If I were you, I would use spinner while data is loading. [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner), for example.

Comment: Could you add some code for adding spinner while the page is getting rendered. It would be great help. I have tried displaying the loader with the $locationChangeStart and $locationChangeSuccess events but that doesn,t work.

Comment: how do you get the data? with $http?

Comment: We have created a service which requests data on demand. Whenever new data is requested it gets pushed to the array. So once user has requested a particular data we don't send request for it again.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is no good for displaying big mount data using ng-repeat, many people are experiencing your problem, you need to optimizing it yourself though it's really Angular's obligation. check here, there is a solution in it. http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/